# How to create two types of collision in a game

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I was trying to create a 2D running game so I tried to define two collision functions. One to end the game if I collide with the obstacles and one to increase my score if I collide with the coin. I defined the collision with obstacles as 'collide' and collision with coin as 'special_collide'. The problem I am facing is that 'collide' is working but 'special_collide' isn't. Here is the code :-

```
# The two functions

def collide(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    distance = math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2)
    return distance <= 27


def special_collide(coinX, coinY, playerX, playerY):
    distance_square = math.pow(coinX - playerX, 2) + math.pow(coinY - playerY, 2)
    if distance_square == 27*27:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Inside the while loop

    # For increasing our score
    s_collision = special_collide(coinX, coinY, playerX, playerY)
    if s_collision:
        print("Special collision occured!")

    # Collision Detection
    obstacles = [(binX, binY), (snowX, snowY), (glacierX, glacierY), (boardX, boardY), (iceX, iceY)]

    for x, y in obstacles:
        collision = collide(x, y, playerX, playerY)
        if collision:
            print("You have collided!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance calculation may be wrong in `special_collide`

Try this code:

```
def special_collide(coinX, coinY, playerX, playerY):
    distance_square = (math.pow(coinX - playerX, 2) + math.pow(coinY - playerY, 2))**.5
    if distance_square <= 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```